# How to use hibernate properly

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following code in my application each time I want to do some action with hibernate:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(obj); //or delete, update etc.
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

This is of course not a good practice. What is the best way to access hibernate and not to have situation like this? Should I use some 'Util' class that contains static methods that do the same job? Maybe singleton is better? I also need to wrap this code in thread or SwingWorker in order not to freeze my GUI while accessing database.

Comment: Why is it not a good practice?

Comment: Usually i use springs declarative Transaction management features to achieve this. It helps keeping the code clean and focus on your business logic. Take a look at [Spring AOP Tx management](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-transaction-management-in-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that code is pretty bad.

1. it opens a transaction for every database access. This is inefficient, and probably incorrect (usually, an entire group of actions needs to be atomic. For instance consider

   ```
   public void buy(String accountId) {
       Account account = load(accountId);
       account.balance -= 100;
       save(account);
   }
   ```

   If load and save are in their own transactions, and some evil user buys 2 items at the same time, the following may happen:

   - thread 1 reads the balance (=1000)
   - thread 2 reads the balance (=1000)
   - thread 1 writes the balance (=900)
   - thread 2 writes the balance (=900)

   so the user bought twice, but only paid once ;-)
2. it does not finish the transaction if save() throws an exception. In fact, the transaction will remain open indefinitely, including all the locks it holds ...

Complexities such as these are the reason most people demarcate transactions declaratively rather than reinventing a square wheel, for instance with [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) or [EJB](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncih.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think to resolve is to acquire renentranlock based on accountId

```
@Service
public class AccountService {
    private Map<String, ReentrantLock> locks = new HashMap<Long, ReentrantLock>();

    private void unlock(String id) {
        ReentrantLock lock = locks.get(id);
        if (lock != null && lock.isLocked()) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void lock(String id) {
        ReentrantLock lock;
        synchronized (locks) {
            lock = locks.get(id);
            if (lock == null) {
                lock = new ReentrantLock();
                locks.put(id, lock);
            }
        }
        lock.lock();
    }

public void buy(String accountId) {
    this.lock(accountId);
    try{
       Account account = load(accountId);
       account.balance -= 100;
       save(account);
    }finally{
      this.unlock(accountId);
    }
   }
}
```

if this functionality is required through out application then it might be wise to write around aspect over service.

Comment: I think some more explanation would help

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to read [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions) article from Hibernate site.

This article is a must for anyone thinking about best way to use sessions and transactions in Hibernate.

Basically the best design pattern would depend upon the transaction management strategy you 
have chosen (jdbc, jta) and the mode of applying transactions ( programmatic / declarative)

As already pointed out by meriton, opening and closing transactions for each method in your code (assuming there would be several such methods working sequentially to form an atomic operation) is an antipattern. This too is discussed in more detail in the article.